# stdenv.mkDerivation with cmake failed to link staticly

Tags: gcc, cmake, nix

I am trying to build [halite](https://github.com/HaliteChallenge/Halite-II/tree/master/environment) with following `default.nix`:

```
with import <nixpkgs> {};

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {
  pname = "halite";
  version = "git";
  name = "${pname}-${version}";
  src = ./.;
  buildInputs = [ cmake ];
}
```

but when I run `nix-build default.nix` it failed to link with following errors:

```
[ 97%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/halite.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable halite
/nix/store/z470j6lybdsy4ql972k392490bprhd2g-binutils-2.28.1/bin/ld: cannot find -lpthread
/nix/store/z470j6lybdsy4ql972k392490bprhd2g-binutils-2.28.1/bin/ld: cannot find -lm
/nix/store/z470j6lybdsy4ql972k392490bprhd2g-binutils-2.28.1/bin/ld: cannot find -lc
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

the full log can be found [here](https://pastebin.com/E6dgSWsm)

I try to fix this but have no success:

- add `gcc`, `pkgconfig` to `buildInputs`
- using `nativeBuildInputs` and `propergatedBuildInputs`

---

What should be the correct way to write `default.nix` and `shell.nix` for `cmake` project?

Comment: From skimming the source it looks like it tries to link the libraries statically, and most Nix packages don't provide those. In this specific case it might be sufficient to add `glibc.static` to your `buildInputs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using `glibc.static` as ppb's [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46888999/stdenv-mkderivation-with-cmake-failed-to-link#comment80740412_46888999), thanks.

Turn out that the problem did not from `default.nix` but from `halite` try to use static link.

When I change `CMakeList.txt` to use dynamic link, the build is fine.